# Почему выводится ошибка?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Пишу твиттер клиент, подключаю при этом к нему библиотеку twitterizer.dll, но выводится следующая ошибка при компиляции:

На строку:

```
using Twitterizer.Framework;
```

Следующую ошибку:
    Не удалось найти имя типа или пространства имен "Twitterizer" (пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку.
    Помогите исправить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References ( Add Reference...)

У вас библиотека добавлена, помимо того что прописан using?

Comment: Да просто даже не представляю, так трудно понять удаленно

Я так понял, вы следуете [документации][1]?

  [1]:http://www.twitterizer.net/documentation/

Comment: @rasmisha Не удалось найти имя типа или пространства имен "Twitterizer" (пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку?) Вот эта ошибка

Comment: @navi1893 Странно сейчас с сайта скачал библиотеку
[twitterizer2.dll][1], и у меня точно такая, только потому что в этом пространстве имен вообще нет такого класса Twitter. (проект .Net 4.0). Вы уверены, что вы правильно пишите всё? (можете дать ссылку на то откуда вы скачали и откуда берете информацию по использованию библиотеки)

 [1]:http://www.twitterizer.net/files/Twitterizer2-2.4.zip

Comment: да, если использовать twitterizer2 бывают такие ошибки, я поэтому начал первую версию использовать. Вот : http://en.sourceforge.jp/frs/g_redir.php?m=jaist&f=%2Felefantpp%2FElefant%2FTwitterizer.Framework.dll и вот: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRfSo4Per4I&list=FLtY5dtGvBMru-squkNlUGLA&index=1&feature=plpp_video

Comment: Создал проект таргет 3.5

    using Twitterizer;

а уже в методе 

    Twitterizer.Framework.Twitter twitter = new Twitterizer.Framework.Twitter("login","pass");

нигде не ругается

Comment: вот вторая ошибка, извини, не видел его чет:


не удалось разрешить указанную ссылкой сборку "Twitterizer.Framework", поскольку она зависит от "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", отсутствующей в текущей целевой платформе ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Удалите ссылки на сборки не в целевой платформе или рассмотрите возможность переориентации проекта. @rasmisha

Comment: Добавляется ссылку не во вкладке обзор (browse) или как там по-русски. А из вкладки .Net ссылку на System.Web

Comment: @rasmisha все сделал! огромное спасибо!))

Answer (score 2):

```
using Twitterizer;
```

Потому что.

Comment: та же самая ошибка. Не исчезает =/

Comment: @niki-timofe в чем проблема??